# Method returned by useState(true) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a basic Signup component, where the User will input the name, email, and password. When the user will click on "Create Account", I want it to hide Signup Form and show **Circular Spinner**. I am using `useState` hook but I am getting the following error on submitting the form:

**Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: isCreating is not a function**

**Signup.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import BounceLoader from "react-spinners/BounceLoader";

const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;



const Signup = () => {
    const { creating, isCreating } = useState(false)
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = async (data) => {

        isCreating(true)

        if (data.password1 === data.password2){
            console.log("Password matched")
        }

        const user = {
            name: data.name,
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password1
        }
      fetch("api/users", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            { creating ?
             <div className="spinner">
             {/* <ClipLoader color={color} loading={loading} css={override} size={150} /> */}
             <div className="spinner-indicator">
               <BounceLoader css={override} size={64} />
             </div>
             <div className="spinner-text">Creating Account...</div>
           </div>

           :


           <div className="authCard">
           <div className="authCardTitle"></div>
   
           <div className="authCardBody">
 
             <div className="right">
               <div className="auth--heading">Sign up with email</div>
               <p className="auth--subheading">
                 Enter your email address to create an account.
               </p>
               <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                 <div className="form--group">
                   <input
                     type="text"
                     className="form--control"
                     placeholder="Your Name"
                     {...register("name")}
                   />
                 </div>
   
                 <div className="form--group">
                   <input
                     type="email"
                     className="form--control"
                     placeholder="Your Email"
                     {...register("email")}
                   />
                 </div>
   
                 <div className="form--group">
                   <input
                     type="password"
                     className="form--control"
                     placeholder="Your Password"
                     {...register("password1")}
                   />
                 </div>
   
                 <div className="form--group">
                   <input
                     type="password"
                     className="form--control"
                     placeholder="Confirm Your Password"
                     {...register("password2")}
                   />
                 </div>
   
                 <div
                   style={{
                     display: "flex",
                     justifyContent: "space-between",
                     alignContent: "center",
                   }}
                 >
                   <div className="form--group">
                     <button
                       class="btn btn--dark btn--filled btn--contact"
                       href="./contact.html"
                     >
                       Continue
                     </button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </form>
   
               <div className="account--exists">
                 <p>
                   Account already exists? <a href="#">Login</a>
                 </p>
               </div>
             </div>
          
       
             
          
           </div>
         </div>
       
        }
        </>

    );
}

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useState returns an array, not an object. Use this:

```
  const [ creating, setCreating ] = useState(false)
```

Also, since the second item in the array is the setter method, it is a convention to prepend it with set